# ruby のドキュメントにおける返り値 "()" の意味

Tags: ruby

`FileUtils.touch`でファイルを生成すると、返り値として生成したファイル名を要素に持つ大きさが`1`の`Array`が返ってきたので、何故`String`ではなく`Array`で返すか知りたくドキュメントを確認した所 返り値の項目が`()`になっていました。

> > touch(list, options = {}) -> ()

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/FileUtils.html#M_TOUCH

Rubyのドキュメントで`()`はどういった意味を持つのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[リファレンスのヘルプ](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/help.html)
によれば「不定」だそうです。